# Why was my answer deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I've read the FAQ and I believe it may be a mistake. It is in the now closed programming books question. This is one of my favorite programming books.

#### [My post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611436/417721)

> 97 things every programmer should know
>
> I read it a few "things" per day over several months. Some of the "things" contradict some other "things" but they are worth reading. If you are interested here is an interview with the editor Kevlin Henney: http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/09/97-things

Comment: It got moved to http://stackoverflow.com/a/392926/17034

Comment: You can edit the answer linked by the above user and put correct link if you think the current link in there is wrong.

Comment: So many downvotes - I thought meta was the place to ask this sort of thing. I included as much detail as I could and choose appropriate tags. I had thought this to be a genuine mistake.

Comment: [Down-votes on meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: I added the link to the top answer shortly after posting my answer. There are a lot of other answers like mine - maybe many others have been deleted too. I must say it was nice having individual answers as well as the list at the top as one could see the most popular books. I found a few nice books this way.

Comment: @adam there are a *lot* of deleted answers on that question, btw.

Comment: @Andrew about 230 deleted answers - moderators were trying to clean it up.

Comment: Burn that question down with fire...230 deleted answers yeesh.

Answer (score 13):

Leaving aside the quality and constructiveness (or otherwise) of the question and concentrating on your answer.

Your answer is little more than a link to the book. There is no explanation of *why* or *how* the book answers the question. Therefore it's not really an answer but a comment (at best).

Answer (score 7):

> I've read the FAQ

Read it again. Carefully. Comb through it with a toothbrush made from unicorn hair.

Especially [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Also [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

The question should have a definite answer.

Your answer satisfies the following  point from the "what shouldn't I ask" part of the faq(linked above)

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

We really prefer stuff with a definite answer. This one is open to discussion/debate/whatnot. So it was closed.

Comment: I realize why the question was closed that is not my concern

Comment: @AdamButler: Hmm.. then it's because the answer's already there in the main CW answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926 (search the page for '97')

Comment: +1 if you tell me where to get such a toothbrush.

Answer (score 2):

Um, [it's on the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392926/50776).

The way that question was maintained (I say *was*, because that reproduction of Amazon's programming book section is now historically locked) is that there was the singular accepted answer (community wiki) which was the collection of all the answers.

Your particular answer was flagged for attention with a custom mod message indicating that it's already on the list, which was verified by BoltClock, and then he deleted the answer.